# Can Canon T7i trigger an unmounted 430EX III-RT?

Tags: wireless-flash

I have a Canon T7i and I need to wirelessly trigger unmounted 430EX III-RT. Can the camera do it on its own or what do I need to make it happen? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your camera can control your flash using optical communication. See page 217 and following of the [Camera manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/4/0300026114/01/eos-rebelt7i-800d-im-en.pdf). You of course have to set the flash to "optical slave" mode ("lightning" icon) and make sure it is on the same channel as the camera.

Tip: in the camera flash settings, you can set the lighting ratio between the camera and the external flash, in general you want to dim the camera flash a bit.

Comment: The built-in wireless flash capabilities of the EOS Rebel T7i/800D and similar bodies  uses *optical* communication, vis a series of pre-flashes, between the camera and flash, not *radio*. Canon has no current bodies with a built-in radio trigger for the RT radio control system. One must use an external radio transmitter (or an external  flash with a built-in radio transmitter) mounted to the camera.

Comment: Yes, edited. So used to my ST-E3...

Answer (score 0):

The existing answer is true only for mid-range cameras. Low-end and high-end cameras do not have the "easy wireless flash" functionality. High-end cameras do not have it, because they lack the integrated flash.

For those wondering the same for low-end and high-end cameras, to trigger 430EX III-RT, you can use either Canon ST-E2 infrared trigger or Canon ST-E3-RT radio trigger (or 600EX-RT as radio master, but that's an expensive route).

Which one of these two to use depends on whether you need non line of sight triggering in outdoor conditions (then ST-E3-RT is the only option), and whether you can find a used ST-E2 from a second-hand market (they are usually very cheap, $50 or so). If one has to buy ST-E2 new, then it's nearly as expensive as ST-E3-RT. I probably wouldn't buy ST-E2 new unless I wanted to trigger second-hand flashes lacking the RT feature. However, if buying flashes second-hand, one can perfectly well buy the ST-E2 second-hand too.

Also, Canon's more expensive flashes (600EX-RT) can work as a radio master to control 430EX III-RT radio slaves.

Additionally, do note the ST-E2 uses peculiar 2CR5 batteries.

Comment: *High-end cameras do not have it, because they lack the integrated flash* Not a valid reason for the modern radio-controlled flashes.

Comment: @xenoid What Canon body has a built-in RT radio transmitter? (Hint: none do). "Easy Wireless Flash" is an *optically* controlled system.

Comment: One can also purchase one of several third party *RT* radio transmitters or *RT* compatible flashes with built-in radio transmitters if one wishes to use radio to control an RT flash.

Answer (score 0):

Can Canon T7i trigger an unmounted 430EX III-RT?

Yes. The built-in popup flash on the EOS Rebel T7i/800D can act as a master flash to control an off camera 430EX III-RT flash.

The camera side of things is covered on pages 220 and following of the [*EOS Rebel T7i/800D Instruction Manual*](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/4/0300026114/01/eos-rebelt7i-800d-im-en.pdf).

The flash side of this method is covered on pages 71 and following of the [*Speedlite 430EX III-RT/Speedlite 430 EX III Instruction Manual*](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/0/0300019910/01/sl430exiii-rt-im-en.pdf).

Please note that this uses the older [*optical*](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/72593/15871) external flash control method, rather than the newer RT [*radio*](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/89829/15871) external flash control method. Other than the need for an additional radio transmitter attached to the camera, [*radio communication* is superior to *optical communication*](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/99643/15871) in just about every other way.